# Control keyboard type for Android EditText (digits only)

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-keypad

I have a custom EditText that I use for input of a sequence of digits.  I set DigitsKeyListener (getInputType() = 2) on it in the class's constructor.

This does the "right thing" on a Galaxy S (4.0).  The keyboard that comes up when the view gains focus only has numbers, "space", period, comma, dash, backspace and "done".

However, on an older 2.2 device, the keyboard that comes up has letters and a much wider range of symbols, none of which I need.

I found an example online that suggested:

```
    setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);
```

at the end of initialization.  That value is "3".  When I do this, the situation is reversed for the two phones.  The keyboard on the Galaxy S now has letters (next to each number, like on a phone) whereas the keyboard on the 2.2 device is what I want (i.e. basically a calculator).

Is there a single unified way to get a "calculator" keyboard that works across versions, or is this a situation where I need to do one thing for SDK versions <= X and another for versions > X?

If so, what should the value of "X" be?  Is this something that changed with a particular major release?

Comment: "Is there a single unified way to get a "calculator" keyboard that works across versions" -- no. "or is this a situation where I need to do one thing for SDK versions <= X and another for versions > X?" -- also no. Users and device manufacturers are free to use whatever input method editors they wish. Developers of input method editors are welcome to use whatever designs they want. Things like `inputType` are hints, not demands. Heck, for some input method editors (e.g., Graffiti), there will be precisely zero keys, because they use other input options (e.g., gestures).

Comment: I asked about SDK versions because I have way to make it do what I want on both 2.2 and 4.0, only the two aren't the same.  To get a calculator input method on 2.2 I setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY).  To get it on 4.0 all I need do is setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER) or set a DigitsKeyListener manually.

Comment: Turns out Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY is the same value as InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE.  So the issue is this:  on some devices, specifying TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER gives a richer keyboard than specifying TYPE_CLASS_PHONE whereas on other devices its the reverse.

Comment: And, as I pointed out, this is all well within the bounds of expectation. Moreover, either of those `TYPE_CLASS` values could give you any sort of keyboard, such as a full QWERTY setup, depending upon what the author of the IME did.

Answer (score 5):

You should set the `inputType` attribute to `"number"`, or do the equivalent runtime call.

Comment: Setting a DigitsKeyListener as the KeyListener does this, at least on 4.0.  The KeyListener interface has a getInputType() method, which I assume Textview uses when figuring out what kind of keyboard to bring up.  Maybe the older versions of TextView don't interrogate registered KeyListeners and I need to explicitly set the input type.  Will try that next.